# my mips code does not print out correct answer

Tags: mips

so I tried this code, took some parts of it from this forum. my answer is not coming okay though. I'm getting weird numbers for min and max. can anyone tell me what did I do wrong?

```
 .text
        .globl __start
__start:                # execution starts here

    la $t0,array        # $t0 will point to the elements
    
    lw $t2,($t0)        # initialize min = a[0]
    lw $t3,($t0)        # initialize max = a[0]
    addi $t4, $s0, 0
    li $t1, 0
    
loop:

    bge $t4, 8, EndLoop
        lw $t2, array($t1)
        bgt $s2, $s0, SetMax
        blt $s2, $s1, SetMin

cont:

    addi $s1, $s1, 4
    addi $t4, $t4, 1
    j loop


SetMax:

    move $t3, $s2
    j cont
SetMin:

    move $t2, $s2
    j cont

EndLoop:
    li $v0 4
        la $a0 ans2
        syscall

    li $v0 1
    la $a0 ($s0)
    syscall

        li $v0 4
    la $a0 Space
    syscall

    li $v0 4
        la $a0 ans1
    syscall
    
    li $v0 1
    la $a0 ($s1)
    syscall
           


    la $a0,endl     # syscal to print out
    li $v0,4        # a new line
    syscall 

    li $v0,10       # Exit
    syscall         # Bye!

 .data
    array:  .word 3,4,2,6,12,7,18,26,2,14,19,7,8,12,13
    
    ans1:   .asciiz "min = "
    ans2:   .asciiz "\nmax = "
    endl:   .asciiz "\n"
    Space:  .asciiz " "
```

Comment: Use the debugger to single step each line of code to verify that it doing what you expect: not just on the first iteration, but also the 2nd.  When you find one that doesn't do what you're expecting, you've found a problem!

Comment: Try to attach names to each register depending on their role, this is the current maximum, this is the loop index... If some name attaches to two different registers or some register is using two names at the same time, the program won't work even on paper.

Comment: The first iteration is a degenerate case for indexing (involving zero and addition), so the 2nd iteration is critical.  If the code works for both the first *and second iteration*, it will most likely work for the rest.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking a question, explain what the program is supposed to do, what the expected and actual output are, and choose a title that is searchable and descriptive like "Finding min and max numbers in an array". Thanks.